# performing grid search for 8 hyperparameters on Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to perform a grid search on a cost function that has 8 different variables:

```
cost_function_1 = lambda x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8: (675 + (x_1-15)**2 + x_1**2 * np.cos(x_1*np.pi)) + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 + x_5^2 + x_6^2 + x_7^2 + x_8^2
```

The variables `x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8` are hyperparameters for my model. Their values are defined as the grid within the interval [-10,30]:

```
X_MIN_1 = -10
X_MAX_1 = 30
x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = x_8 = np.linspace(X_MIN_1, X_MAX_1, 10)
```

If my cost function `cost_function_1` only has 1 variable, I would do my grid search like the following:

```
def get_best_value(f, candidates):
    """
    Return the candidate that yielded the lowest cost in the function f.
    :param f: cost function
    :param candidates: x candidates
    :return: the best candidate
    """
    idx_min = np.argmin(f(candidates))
    return candidates[idx_min]

def run_grid_search_experiment(f, n_trials, X_MIN, X_MAX):
    """
    Run the experiment for grid search.
    :param f: cost function
    :param n_trials: number of trials
    :param show_plot: show plot if true
    :return: the best candidate
    """
    gs_candidates = np.linspace(X_MIN, X_MAX, n_trials)
    selected_value = get_best_value(f, gs_candidates)

    return selected_value

gs_selected_value = run_grid_search_experiment(cost_function_1, 
                                               10, -10, 30)
```

However, I am not exactly sure how I can modify the functions `get_best_value` and `run_grid_search_experiment` to work with my cost function `cost_function_1`, which has 8 different variables. For example, the statement `idx_min = np.argmin(f(candidates))` within  the python function `get_best_value` wouldn't work since each candidate would be a numpy array of dimension 1 x 8 (since there are 8 variables to consider).

Can someone help me how I can modify the functions `get_best_value` and `run_grid_search_experiment` to perform the grid search for the 8 variables?

Comment: There's a basic but decent gridsearch implementation in sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: @Swier Hello, thank you for your comment. In this `model_selection` function, I see that the `estimator` argument can be used to specify the "score function". Would this "score function" be my cost function `cost_function_1`? sorry if I am slow to understand.

Comment: Did you mean `x_2**2` instead of `x_2^2` in your function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant your function to be:

```
cost_function_1 = lambda x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8: (675 + (x_1-15)**2 + x_1**2 * np.cos(x_1*np.pi)) + x_2**2 + x_3**2 + x_4**2 + x_5**2 + x_6**2 + x_7**2 + x_8**2
X_MIN_1 = -10.
X_MAX_1 = 30.
n_trials = 10
x = np.linspace(X_MIN_1, X_MAX_1, n_trials)
#create a grid for 8-dimensional search, you can have per dimension specific linespace too.
X = np.meshgrid(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x)
#find function values on grid
out = cost_function_1(*X)
#find index of minimum
idx = np.unravel_index(out.argmin(), out.shape)
#find corresponding value of grid
[x[idx[i]] for i in np.arange(8)]
```

output for above values:

```
[-1.1111111111111107, 21.111111111111114, -1.1111111111111107, -1.1111111111111107, -1.1111111111111107, -1.1111111111111107, -1.1111111111111107, -1.1111111111111107]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. From your code above, what would be the most effective way to find the minimal `cost_function_1` value that results from those grids for the 8 variables? So basically, what if I want to find the value of the `cost_function_1` at the values `[x[idx[i]] for i in np.arange(8)]`? Thank you,